# Android-Blackberry GCM: Can't register ported android app to GCM services

Tags: android, blackberry-android, blackberry-push

We are having some issues registering our device so we can get push notifications in our android ported app.

Here's our scenario:

-We have a Blackberry 10 Dev Alpha device with OS version: 10.0.9.388

-Already registered to the push service

-Created android.cfg and changed values with the ones received from Blackberry :

-Added manifest permissions.

-We deploy the app using a Debug Token.

-Device is connected to Blackberry network (we can add contacts, chat through BBM, etc.)

-Structure of the generated .bar file seem to be ok. (.apk, manifest -permissions are ok too-, android.cfg)

GCM is working fine on Android devices, but, when we debug it on BlackBerry dev alpha device, register method from GCMRegistrar class is not registering our device and getRegistrationId method is always returning an empty string.

There is no exception being thrown, so we don't know what is failing in the register method.
Is there a way to see some logs?

We tried to connect to the device through SSH but we don't know where to find some logs about this (if there are any) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating OS version from 10.0.9.388 to 10.0.10.263, our GCM implementation started working (advice by people from Blackberry Support team).

We got the registration id after calling GCMRegistrar.register and now we are getting notifications!
So there is no need to use Blackberry SDK or any other third party library.

If you are porting your android app to blackberry, make sure your android.cfg is well formed and with valid data received from Blackberry mail after registration for push services.
Also check if push notification permission are in the manifest file in your repackaged .bar file.

Answer (score 0):

GCM will not work on a BlackBerry device, as GCM is part of the Google Services, which are served through Google Play. Any device that doesn't have Google Play (like the Dev Alpha) will not be able to use GCM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Raghav, i know that GCM won't work without Google Play but I thought that maybe Blackberry did some magic on its Android Runtime, something like wrapping the gcm api.
Quoting: http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/creating_push-enabled_android_apps.html 
"[...] When you register for a Push Service, you receive a registration ID unique to your device. BlackBerry registration IDs contain 8 characters. [...]
I don't know how to get that 8 character registration id.

Comment: @ale.m They're saying you need to use BlackBerry's own push system in your app, instead of GCM. They both fo the same thing, but are independent systems

Comment: So there is no way to implement it without using Blackberry Java SDK right?

Comment: @ale.m Maybe it would work if you used a third party service like Urban Airship, but I can't say for sure.