# GPS and GCM ID not works in BlackBerry

Tags: android, eclipse, blackberry-10

I have created an android app, that is converted in BlackBerry app using Plugin in Eclipse.

In Android the all the functionality works good, but in BlackBerry GPS and GCM ID not works.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15074199/android-blackberry-gcm-cant-register-ported-android-app-to-gcm-services visit this link

Comment: https://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/Google-Cloud-Messaging-Not-getting-a-registration-id/td-p/2192139